# Different types of Listeners in Android

Tags: android, listener, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have an Activity which contains TextViews, Spinners, TimePickers, etc. and I would like to perform a task only when the button OK is clicked. For that, I set a listener on each component. My problem is : there are a few types of listeners that I use (onClickListener, onItemSelectedListener, etc.) so each listener needs his own method (onClickListener needs the method `public void onClick(View v){};` onItemSelectedListener needs the method `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {}`) but I would like to perform one task with all these information only once (when the button OK is pressed) so this should be declared in the onClick() method. But how can I manage the other values if it has to be managed each time in a different method than the one who needs it?

Comment: "For that, I set a listener on each component. " <-- Why? You should only set the onClickListener on the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to listen to only the 'OK' button, then set a listener for only that button. Why would you set a listener for other items at all?

For the 'OK' button, you can set a listener like this:

```
okButton.setOnClickListener( new onClickListener{

public void onClick(View v) {

     //do what you need to inside the listener here

    }

});
```